# Terraform: Use module instance's name inside module

Tags: terraform

I am using a Terraform module to deploy resources, using separate instances to deploy sets of those resources.  I would like to be able to name those resources according to the instance's name.  For example:

```
module "thing1" {
   source = "my-module"
   param1 = "value the first"
   param2 = "value the second"
}
```

And in the module:

```
resource "resource_type" "doesntmatter" {
   name = "${module.self.name}"
   ...
}
```

In the example, I would like the resource to have the name `thing1`.

I could certainly just create another variable for input to the module but that is repetitive for the client code (violates DRY--the created resource needs a reasonable identifier, but nothing pretty, so it would be good to reuse a descriptive instance name) and this seems like it should be available, but I can't see anything in the Terraform documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do this at the moment, you will have to go with the parameter.

Comment: That seems to match everything else I've found.